# Pandas not able to handle vulgar fraction in python server

Tags: python, pandas, linux, unix, encoding

I am reading an excel file using python and pandas read excel in Unix based python server where I am encoding these [vulgar fraction strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6Px7.png) in utf-8, because I was getting encoding error in python once they are encoded they look like this [encoded vulgar fractions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY51W.png), after this I am inserting this data in SQL server.

So problem is

1. I do this process in python server all these vulgar fractions get loaded in DB as this [Junk Chars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oshHv.png)
2. When I do this process in my local system in jupyter my data is getting loaded as intended.

Version in local system :- Python  3.8+ Pandas : 1.1.5
Version in python server:- Python  3.6+ Pandas : 1.1.5

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I think that neither pandas nor SQL server can make sense of vulgar fractions as a unicode character; you may have to change the formatting of your spreadsheet?

Comment: but when I am using jupyter and inserting in SQL its working don't know why it is not working in python server